# error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt When trying to decrypt with same key and VI

Tags: node.js, encryption

This is my first question ever on stack overflow. I am trying to build a little tool I can use to encrypt and decrypt configuration files. I am generating a secret key for all the files and then passing that key to the encrypt function. Then when I go to decrypt i am reading the key from the file and passing that to the decrypt function. Same with the initVector.
I can encrypt just fine but when I go to decrypt I get the "bad decrypt" error.
Below is the code.
Please forgive the sloppy code, I am new to this and I am just trying to get it to work, I will refactor and clean it up once it does.
Thank you.

```
const crypto = require ("crypto")
const fs = require ("fs")
var prompt = require('prompt');
const Crypt = require('./crypt.js')

var eschema = {
    properties: {
      fpath: {
        description: 'Enter path to files to encrypt: ',
        type: 'string',
        default: "./config/unsafe"
      },
      epath: {
        description: 'Enter path to store encrypted files: ',
        type: 'string',
        default: "./encrypted"
      },
      kpath: {
        description: 'Enter path to store key and vector files: ',
        type: 'string',
        default: "./"
      }
    }
  };

  var dschema = {
    properties: {
      fpath: {
        description: 'Enter path to files to decrypt: ',
        type: 'string',
        default: "./encrypted"
      },
      dpath: {
        description: 'Enter path to store decrypted files: ',
        type: 'string',
        default: "./"
      },
      vpath: {
        description: 'Enter path to key and vector files: ',
        type: 'string',
        default: "./"
      }
    }
  };
  console.log(process.argv[2])

if(process.argv[2] == '-e'){
    prompt.start()
    prompt.get(eschema, function (err, result){
      if(err){
        throw err;
      }
        iv = crypto.randomBytes(16)
        k = crypto.randomBytes(32)
        let vector = iv.toString('hex').slice(0, 16);
        let key = k.toString('hex').slice(0,32)
        Crypt.encrypt(key, vector, result.fpath, result.epath)
        fs.mkdir(result.epath, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            fs.writeFile(result.kpath +`key`, key, err => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err)
                }
                
            })
            fs.writeFile(result.kpath +`vector`, vector, err => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err)
                }
                
        
            })
        })

    })
    

}else if(process.argv[2] == '-d'){
    prompt.start()
    prompt.get(dschema, function (err, result){
      if(err){
        throw err;
      }
        let key = fs.readFileSync(result.vpath + "key" )
        let vector =  fs.readFileSync(result.vpath + "vector")
        
        Crypt.decrypt(key, vector, result.fpath)


    })
    

}else{
    console.log("Please pass 'encrypt' or 'decrypt'")
}
```

```
const crypto = require ("crypto")
const fs = require ("fs")

class Crypt {
 

    encrypt(key, vector, path, epath){
        fs.readdir(path, (err, files) => {
            if (err) {
            throw err
        }
        console.log(key)
        console.log(vector)
            files.forEach(file => {
                console.log("Encrypting: " + file)
                let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-256-cbc", key, vector);
                let rfile = path + "/" + file
                let data = fs.readFileSync(rfile)
                let encryptedData = cipher.update(data, "utf-8", "hex");
                encryptedData += cipher.final("hex");
                let eobj = {
                    vi: vector,
                    content: encryptedData
                }
                fs.writeFile(epath + '/' + file + '.enc', encryptedData, err => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err)
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    }

    decrypt(key, vector, path, dpath){
        fs.readdir(path, (err, files) => {
            if (err){
            throw err
        }
            console.log("Decrypting:")
            console.log(files)
            files.forEach(file => {
                let rfile = path + "/" + file
                let data = fs.readFileSync(rfile)
                console.log('Key: ' + key)
                console.log('Vector: ' + vector)
                let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-256-cbc", key, vector);
                let decryptedData = decipher.update(data, "hex", "utf-8")
                decryptedData += decipher.final("utf8");
                console.log("Decrypted message: " + decryptedData);
            })
        })
    }
}
module.exports = new Crypt
```

Answer (score 0):

The fix to this was that I wasnt passing the vector as binary but instead as a string and that caused the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.